# Could not add entry ':app:sourceSets' to cache taskArtifacts.bin

Tags: java, android

Very new to programming and Android Studio.

Getting a problem when trying to run my program, can anybody help?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not add entry ':app:sourceSets' to cache taskArtifacts.bin (/Users/marcelgarvey/AndroidStudioProjects/SimpleTipCalculator/.gradle/2.4/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin).

  > Unable to store task input properties. Property 'config' with value 'com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@a8d1ae3' cannot be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing (well I do), but I'm kinda new to Android Studio as well.

Seeing as I just sumpled into the same problem, and google pointed here, I thought I'd add my observations/fix.

**What created the problem:**

I accidentally double-clicked sourceSets under the Gradle pane. (:app/Tasks/android/sourceSets)

And whenever building the project the same error came up.

**What happened/fixed it:**

It had changed the build profile (right next to the Run and Debug buttons), to something about that sourceSets.
Changing the build profile back fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the file: taskArtifacts.bin localised in the .gradle folder, and put a space on gradle file and sync.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this issue.  I think this might be a bug in Gradle.  Here is some information I was able to find:

"This exception indicates that Gradle cannot persist the Task execution state when the Task successfully completes, because some element in the Task state is not Serializable." ([Source](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/uncheckedioexception-could-not-add-entry-to-cache-taskartifacts-bin/2023))

It appears that sourceSetsTask has a property called "config" of type AndroidConfig that is not serializable, and that's what is causing the error. ([Source](https://github.com/yeungeek/android-platform-tools-base/blob/master/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/tasks/SourceSetsTask.java))